Make path as a subdomain in Cloudflare
How to point a path to a subdomain in Cloudflare?
For example, I have a webpage with a path www.example.com/path and I am expecting that user can access the website via a registered subdomain, such as path.example.com or www.custom.com.
Is that possible? How?
